# How to delete a big folder permanently and quickly

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I noticed my hard drive filling up every time I cleared space, for no reason so I downloaded an app which helped me find out which files are taking up the most space. My hard drive is around 450 GB large and I don't know any files that take that much space on my computer (my games are on a separate SSD).

I found out that there was a crash report folder that had thousands of files in it, adding up to 417 GB. How can I delete this folder? I tried deleting it the normal way but it would just take days as it is literally too many files. Also where does this come from, is this a virus?
Location of folder:

C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Local\CEF\User Data\CrashPad\reports

I'm running windows 10.

Comment: Step 1: Select Folder; Step 2: Press the Delete key.  It will NOT take days to delete 417 GB, might take a couple hours, if it takes days then you have hardware issues.

Comment: For improved speed consider Shift+Delete to skip the recycle bin.

Comment: I do not, sorry

Comment: @2000mroliver - My suggestion was dead serious.  Your sarcastic response to my suggestion is not appreciated.  "Is this a virus? " - **No**, it is not a virus.  The files were generated by **Chrome Embedded Framework**

Comment: Based on this: [Question regarding CEF folder and WidewineCDM](https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/174785-question-regarding-cef-folder-and-widewinecdm/) Steam created the files.  So while you can delete the files, they will just be generated again, so you should just leave them alone.

Comment: So your telling me I should just leave the 400 GB worth of useless reports alone.... Also my response to your comment was dead serious, your post was obviously sarcastic and I found it useless to me as I have already had actual useful answers posted on my question. Please refrain from posting on my question again, thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can speed up deleting significantly by doing it from the command prompt.

Here's how to do it:

1. Click on an empty part in the addressbar so you can type in it.
2. Clear the entire addressbar and type in cmd and press enter.
3. A command prompt window is opened with the explorer's folder set as its starting folder.
4. Type `del *.*` to delete all files.

I don't know how important the folder itself is, but I found out that `rd MyFolder /s` is even faster, as it skips checking for any files and just removes the entry to the files itself (Should be instantly removed). You then have to recreate the folder. Do note rd removes all files and subfolders including the folder you want to remove. If you don't want to remove everything, this is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid Window's copy/move routines are just slow, compounded by NTFS also being slow.
No way round that.

If you've got a nix or Mac machine you could drop the drive into temporarily [assuming NTFS write capability was enabled, it's not natively], that would be far quicker.

Comment: I disagree. command prompt is pretty fast, if you use del, or instant if you use rd, but that also removes the folder itself.

Comment: @LPChip: `rd /s` is not instant by any means.  You must only ever delete directories with very few files in them.  Once you get to 100s or 1000s or 10000s of files and sub-folders, it can take quite a noticeable length of time.

Comment: @AdrianPronk thanks for the headsup. I tested it with a few large files only, and that seemed instant. I bet its still faster than del *.* or using the explorer though.

Comment: @LPChip - tbh, I don't use Win command line much at all, so I was comparing using the GUI. I spend most of my life on Macs, but have to admin a few Win machines in the same building, & I always despair at how long it takes to do a simple file move or delete, even if I bypass the Trash.

Answer (score 0):

I find using `robocopy` is much faster, especially if gazillions of little files. It is also the easiest way to delete files that exceed the 256-charter limit.

The concept is to mirror an empty directory and make use of Multiple Threads ie:

1. Create an empty folder. `C:\tempdir` will do.
2. From CMD prompt:

```
Robocopy c:\tempdir d:\delete_me /r:0 /MIR /MT:16
```

Enhance it further by adding:

- `/l` to dry-run (no changes made to files)
- `/MT:32` or `/MT:64` if your processor will handle it.
- `/nfl` and `/ndl` to exclude folder and directory names in report
- `/np` to exclude progress
- `/xj` to exclude junction points and symbolic links (just in case!)
- `/log:c:\temp.txt` to output to text file instead of console